# How does YouTube iOS app render the loading page?

Tags: ios, image, youtube, placeholder

Just want to confirm, is the following gray section from YouTube iOS app just placeholder image? I saw a few apps make like this, if not, how do they implement that?

[image: youtube-ios-loading-page]

Comment: Use [SkeletonView](https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView)

Comment: @RajeshKumarR That's the one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this if you want to achieve it without integrating a pods.

```
    import UIKit

    @objc public protocol ListLoadable
    {
      func ld_visibleContentViews()->[UIView]
    }

  @objc extension UITableView : ListLoadable
  {
   public func ld_visibleContentViews()->[UIView]
   {
    return (self.visibleCells as NSArray).value(forKey: "contentView") as! 
   [UIView]
  }
  }

  @objc extension UIView
    {
      public func showShimmeryLoader(){
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    if self is UITableView{
        ListLoader.addLoaderTo(self as! UITableView)
    }else if self is UICollectionView{
        ListLoader.addLoaderTo(self as! UICollectionView)
    }else{
        ListLoader.addLoaderToViews([self])
    }
     }

     public func hideShimmeryLoader(){
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    if self is UITableView{
        ListLoader.removeLoaderFrom(self as! UITableView)
    }else if self is UICollectionView{
        ListLoader.removeLoaderFrom(self as! UICollectionView)
    }else{
        ListLoader.removeLoaderFromViews([self])
    }
    }
     }

   @objc extension UICollectionView : ListLoadable
   {
     public func ld_visibleContentViews()->[UIView]
    {
         return (self.visibleCells as NSArray).value(forKey: "contentView") as! 
   [UIView]
        }
    }



   @objc extension UIColor {
    static func backgroundFadedGrey()->UIColor
    {
        return UIColor(red: (246.0/255.0), green: (247.0/255.0), blue: 
  (248.0/255.0), alpha: 1)
}

static func gradientFirstStop()->UIColor
{
    return  UIColor(red: (238.0/255.0), green: (238.0/255.0), blue: 
(238.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
}

static func gradientSecondStop()->UIColor
{
    return UIColor(red: (221.0/255.0), green: (221.0/255.0), blue:(221.0/255.0) 
  , alpha: 1.0);
    }
  }

  @objc extension UIView{
func boundInside(_ superView: UIView){

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    superView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: 
    "H:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), 
     metrics:nil, views:["subview":self]))
    superView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: 
     "V:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), 
    metrics:nil, views:["subview":self]))
     }
    }

       extension CGFloat
   {
     func doubleValue()->Double
     {
      return Double(self)
      }
    }



    @objc open class ListLoader: NSObject
     {
      static func addLoaderToViews(_ views : [UIView])
     {
    CATransaction.begin()
    views.forEach { $0.ld_addLoader() }
    CATransaction.commit()
}

static func removeLoaderFromViews(_ views: [UIView])
{
    CATransaction.begin()
    views.forEach { $0.ld_removeLoader() }
    CATransaction.commit()
}

public static func addLoaderTo(_ list : ListLoadable )
{
    self.addLoaderToViews(list.ld_visibleContentViews())
}


public static func removeLoaderFrom(_ list : ListLoadable )
   {
    self.removeLoaderFromViews(list.ld_visibleContentViews())
   }
 }

     @objc class CutoutView : UIView
   {
     override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.setFillColor(UIColor.rgb(red: 231, green: 235, blue: 229, alpha: 
      1).cgColor)
          context?.fill(self.bounds)

        for view in (self.superview?.subviews)! {

             if view != self {
            context?.setBlendMode(.clear);
            let rect = view.frame
            let clipPath: CGPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, 
         cornerRadius: view.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
            context?.addPath(clipPath)
            context?.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
            context?.closePath()
            context?.fillPath()
        }
    }
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.superview?.ld_getGradient()?.frame = (self.superview?.bounds)!
}
  }

  // TODO :- Allow caller to tweak these

   var cutoutHandle: UInt8         = 0
 var gradientHandle: UInt8       = 0
  var loaderDuration              = 0.85
   var gradientWidth               = 0.17
  var gradientFirstStop           = 0.1



  @objc extension UIView
  {
fileprivate func ld_getCutoutView()->UIView?
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &cutoutHandle) as! UIView?
}

fileprivate func ld_setCutoutView(_ aView : UIView)
{
    return objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &cutoutHandle, aView, 
   .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
}

fileprivate func ld_getGradient()->CAGradientLayer?
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &gradientHandle) as! CAGradientLayer?
}

fileprivate func ld_setGradient(_ aLayer : CAGradientLayer)
{
    return objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &gradientHandle, aLayer, 
  .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
}

fileprivate func ld_addLoader()
{
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width , height: 
 self.bounds.size.height)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at:0)

    self.configureAndAddAnimationToGradient(gradient)
    self.addCutoutView()
}

fileprivate func ld_removeLoader()
{
    self.ld_getCutoutView()?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.ld_getGradient()?.removeAllAnimations()
    self.ld_getGradient()?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    for view in self.subviews {
        view.alpha = 1
    }
}


func configureAndAddAnimationToGradient(_ gradient : CAGradientLayer)
{
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: -1.0 + CGFloat(gradientWidth), y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0 + CGFloat(gradientWidth), y: 0)

    gradient.colors = [
        UIColor.backgroundFadedGrey().cgColor,
        UIColor.gradientFirstStop().cgColor,
        UIColor.gradientSecondStop().cgColor,
        UIColor.gradientFirstStop().cgColor,
        UIColor.backgroundFadedGrey().cgColor
    ]

    let startLocations = [NSNumber(value: gradient.startPoint.x.doubleValue() 
      as Double),NSNumber(value: gradient.startPoint.x.doubleValue() as 
    Double),NSNumber(value: 0 as Double),NSNumber(value: gradientWidth as 
     Double),NSNumber(value: 1 + gradientWidth as Double)]


    gradient.locations = startLocations
    let gradientAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    gradientAnimation.fromValue = startLocations
    gradientAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber(value: 0 as Double),NSNumber(value: 1 
      as Double),NSNumber(value: 1 as Double),NSNumber(value: 1 + 
        (gradientWidth - gradientFirstStop) as Double),NSNumber(value: 1 + 
    gradientWidth as Double)]

    gradientAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    gradientAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    gradientAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    gradientAnimation.duration = loaderDuration
    gradient.add(gradientAnimation ,forKey:"locations")


    self.ld_setGradient(gradient)

}

fileprivate func addCutoutView()
{
    let cutout = CutoutView()
    cutout.frame = self.bounds
    cutout.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    self.addSubview(cutout)
    cutout.setNeedsDisplay()
    cutout.boundInside(self)

    for view in self.subviews {
        if view != cutout {
            view.alpha = 0
        }
    }


    self.ld_setCutoutView(cutout)
  }
   }
```